# XlsxWriter: add color to cells

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I try to write dataframe to xlsx and give color to that.
I use

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:C1', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
```

But it's not give color to cell. And I want to one color to this cells.
I saw `cell_format.set_font_color('#FF0000')`
but there is don't specify number of cells

```
sex = pd.concat([df2[["All"]],df3], axis=1)
excel_file = 'example.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
sex.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

format = workbook.add_format()

format.set_pattern(1)
format.set_bg_color('gray')
worksheet.write('A1:C1', 'Ray', format)

writer.save()
```

I need to give color to `A1:C1`, but I should give `name` to cell. How can I paint several cells of my df?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `worksheet.write('A1:C1', 'Ray', format)` is used only to write a single cell. 
A possible solution to write more cells in a row, is use `write_row()`.

```
worksheet.write_row("A1:C1", ['Ray','Ray2','Ray3'], format)
```

Remember that **write_row()** takes a list of string to write in cells.

If you use `worksheet.write_row("A1:C1", 'Ray', format)`, you have **R** in the first cell, **a** in second and **y** in the third.

Comment: I try this `format = workbook.add_format()

format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
format.set_bg_color('green')

worksheet.write('A1:C1', 'Ray', format)`  but it give color only to `A!`. How can I paint `B1` and  `C1` too?

Comment: can you edit your question with complete script please?

Comment: But if I don't need to write anything to cell, I only want to paint that, is it real?

Comment: a possible workaround is worksheet.write_row("A1:C1", ['','',''], format)

Answer (score 1):

```
cf = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})
worksheet.write('A1', 'Column name', cf)
```